# How install JCL and JVCL on Delphi 11.3 CE version

Tags: delphi, jedi

Jcl and JCVL create no lib! -> Radstudio\Tools\jcl-2.8.0.8551\source\vcl"
This version of the product does not support command line compiling.?????

So I have to run it manually, but....
How can I see what a runtime package is or design time packages.
Is there a batch file for install without JediInstaller ?

Answer (score 5):

Search on jcl directory the packages folder. Open the projectGroup file for your versión; For example:

*c:\local\Componentes\Jcl\jcl-2.8.0.8014\packages\JclPackages**D280**.groupproj*

Compile All packages of group:

[image]

If your compilation is ok, install the packages that have the "install" option (the green icon in the image -runtime packages haven't this opcion-).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Installation Jcl successful. Now I thought: Ok The same procedure also applies to Jcvl... not so, Too bad. Can jou help me ? So what should I do now?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much
Learned something again at 73

Latest version Jcl and Jcvl downloaded
Last jedi.inc downloaded and in the folder
U:\Delphi\2023\jcl-2.8.0.8556\source\include\jedi.
Installation Jcl perfect.
The latest Jedi inc in the folder U:\Delphi\JCL-JCVL\2023\JVCL3-2023-08-04\common\jedi
Installation Jcvl perfect

Very good, Thanks again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for JVCL is basically the same, except for a few things to keep in mind.

1. JVCL needs certain JCL files.
   a) First you have to compile JCL and then JVCL.
   b) It will be necessary to indicate to the JVCL where the JCL files are.

When you compile JCL be aware of where these files are being left.

Access to "Options..." of one package of JCL.

[image]

In "options" dialog, copy the "DCP output directory". All the packeges of JCL have the same.

[image]

Localize this directory on disck. In my case is:

```
c:\local\Delphi\Comps\Jcl\jcl-2.8.0.8014\lib\d28\win32\
```

You must now add that directory to the IDE's configuration for the JVCL build to find them.

1. Open de JVCL package for your version
2. Go "Tools/Options" to configure the IDE to find necessary files.
3. Add the above directory with the necessary files

[image]

Now, you can try to Compile and Install the JVCL packages.

Answer (score 0):

For the JCL, the "Manual installation" section of the Readme.txt file has the required explanation: https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl/blob/master/jcl/docs/Readme.txt#L135

For the JVCL, the "Manual install for Delphi" section of the install.html file has the required explanation: https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl/blob/master/jvcl/help/install.htm#L293

Answer (score 0):

If you landed on this in your search for how to install the Jedi Code Library in RAD Studio and cannot due to the, "This version of the product does not support command line compiling" error, these notes are from my successful installation of JCL in Delphi 11.

Start by 'installing' the Jedi Code Library in GetIt. You will get to the point where the installation process tries to compile then fails.

Close RAD Studio.

You need to know what package number you need for your RAD Studio version.
…CatalogRerpository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\docs\Readme.txt has a list of include files in its Manual Installation section. Find your version and make a note of the file names. I manually installed for Delphi/RAD Studio 11.3 so these were the relevant file names:

```
For Delphi 11 and C++Builder 11 Win32: source\include\jcld28win32.inc 
For Delphi 11 and C++Builder 11 Win64: source\include\jcld28win64.inc
```

The key number is d28 from "jcl-d28-win32.inc."

If you search your system for those include files, you will not find them yet. They get generated later.

Honestly, I do not know if all of the tools are required but I built all three. Compile the JCL installer tools in this order:

```
1. JediIncCheck
2. JCLCmdStarter
3. JediInstaller
```

Find your Catalog Repository. The default location is in your 'My Documents' folder. (I moved mine out of range of OneDrive for performance reasons.)

In RAD Studio...

Open and build:

…CatalogRepository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\install\JediIncCheck.dproj

Open and build:

…CatalogRepository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\install\build\JCLCmdStarter.dproj

Open and build:
…CatalogRepository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\install\JediInstaller.dproj

Now run the installer program you built:

…CatalogRerpository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\bin\JediInstaller.exe

In the JediInstaller program, open the **MPL License** tab and agree with the terms of the license. Click the **Install** button. Close the JediInstaller application.

Open RAD Studio and respond **YES** to the prompts for loading non-existing libraries on next startup.

In RAD Studio, open the group project that corresponds to the key number you found in the Readme.txt file (d28 in this example [the project file has D28 in the name]):

…CatalogRepository\JEDICodeLibraryJCL-2023.11\packages\JclPackagesD280.groupproj

Respond **YES** to the many prompts for missing packages.

**Build all** in JclPackagesD280. Build for both **Build Configurations** for all. Build with both configurations and **Target Platforms** for the projects that have both x86 and x64 platforms.

Install the runtime packages that have that option using the right-click menu on them.

Restart RAD Studio. You should see no errors for missing libraries.