# How to install JCL and JVCL in Delphi 11.3 CE jvcl version [dcc32 Fatal Error] JVCL.INC(26): F1026 File not found: 'jedi\jedi.inc'

Tags: delphi

Good morning, after doing everything as indicated by the installation and trying to install the jcvl, it shows me this error: [dcc32 Fatal Error] JVCL.INC(26): F1026 File not found: 'jedi\jedi.inc'

[image: Error message]

I hope they can solve the problem.
I know it is the jedi.inc file. I don't know where I should declare it.

I was installing the jvcl version after following the mentioned guide: [How install JCL and JVCL on Delphi 11.3 CE version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801479/how-install-jcl-and-jvcl-on-delphi-11-3-ce-version/76803598?noredirect=1#comment135446992_76803598)
and I get the error shown above.

Comment: You obviously missed to add one or more paths to the library search path

Answer (score 0):

1. Search in your JCL\JVCL library for JVCL.INC
2. Add that path project\options\search path
   If you still have a problem change 'jedi\jedi.inc' to
   full path like c:....jedi.inc
   or
   3.add jedi directory under where is your source
   add there jedi.inc
   so the compiler will find the file